# Portabilidade de C em Linux

Tags: c, linux, portabilidade

Estou começando a usar o [Compilr](https://compilr.com/) e lá eles usam Linux. Estou tendo alguns problemas como por exemplo imprimir um arquivo de texto. Vejam meu programa, ele funciona em windows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/*
escreva um programa que leia o nome de 10 pessoas e armaene esses nomes no arquivo de texto nomes.txt
*/

int main()
{
FILE *arquivo;
int i;
char nome[40], c;

arquivo=fopen("nomes.txt", "a");

printf("digite os 10 nomes:\n");

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    gets(nome);
    fprintf(arquivo,"%s \n",nome);
}

fclose(arquivo);

arquivo=fopen("nomes.txt", "r+");

while((c=getc(arquivo))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",c);

return 0;
}
```

O que há de diferente entre a escrita no Linux e no Windows para eu poder começar a usar o Fedora.

Comment: Qual o problema apresentado? Você sabe se o Compilr dá suporte a escrita de arquivo? Esses sites não costumam dar acesso a IO exceto o console que é redirecionado para a página web. O problema pode ser este.

Comment: "O maior truque que C já fez foi convencer o mundo que não tem uma biblioteca de tempo de execução". “The greatest trick that C ever pulled was convince the world that it does not have a runtime”. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/8/18/beautiful-native-libraries/

Comment: o que eu quero saber é o seguinte `arquivo=fopen("nomes.txt", "r+");

while((c=getc(arquivo))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",c);` é para ler no windows no lunux é como?

Comment: Exceto que você não deveria NUNCA usar `gets`, não vejo erro algum no seu código e ele deveria funcionar normalmente no Linux e Windows. Se você não postar qual o erro que esta obtendo, não há como ajudarmos mais. Utilizo Gentoo, testei o código exatamente como você o escreveu e ele funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, rodei seu código no Ubuntu e compilou de boa... apenas apareceu a mensagem:

teste.c:18:5: warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     gets(nome);
     ^
/tmp/ccQhpYWR.o: na função `main':
teste.c:(.text+0x45): aviso: the`gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

mas tá rodando... pelo que dei uma olhada por aqui esse erro é que essa função gets já está ultrapassada; o compilador roda mas dá esse aviso aí... testei aqui no lugar desse gets o fgets(nome, 100, stdin)... deu certo de boa.

Comment: obrigado eu sei que gets é ultrapassado mas a professora pede assim hahaha mas ja resolvi esse problema ai =) muito obrigado